How do I install swing in eclipse on Windows
I downloaded my eclipse ide from here:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/
and the jdk from here:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk22-windows
but I cant write code that requires swing. So far I don't really have any code just:
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    }
}

In "Window" > "Preferences" I added "Standard VM" and choose the directory with the jdk yet the line:
import javax.swing.JFrame;

still returns an error. I tried making a new project where in the JRE section i choose in "use a project specific JRE" the newly added jdk but that didn't help. The default JRE is JavaSE-17. What should I do? I feel like this really shouldn't be a problem but I'm lost.

maybe the error message tells what the error is ?! we cannot see it, when you do not include it in the question...

(hint, if error is something like "type javax.swing.JFrame is not accessible": remove the module-info.java file or add requires java.desktop; to that file) ||| (swing must not be installed, it is part of the JDK/JRE) ||| see also Understanding Java 9 Modules

Swing is part of standard Java but if you are using the Java module system you must say that you want to use it. You are using the module system if you have a module-info.java file in the project. You can delete that to stop using modules.

Thanks @user85421 that solved the problem but i can't choose a comment as a best anwser.

please include the error message in the question

@user85421 The user said that the problem was solved by another comment which is why I suggested that duplicate.

@dan1st sorry, what? my comment was addressed to OP - I have not included something like @dan1st in previous comment

Is there much of a point in including the error message when the issue is solved already?

@dan1st assuming the last comment is indeed addressed to me, and not to OP  - yes, the point of adding missing information to the question is to make it complete or better and so someone can write a real answer, not just a comment (and my comment was a reply to OP's (indirect) request for an answer they can accept) - not sure why that is bothering you?!
